# Проблемы с получением результатов из ThreadPoolExecutor.map Python

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность

я уже задавал вопрос в этом посте  [Возможно ли ускорить обработку hdf5 файла с помощью threading Python 3.6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1161686/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-hdf5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-threading-python-3-6). Я продвинулся немного дальше, но теперь возникает проблема с получением результатов из map объекта: кажется, что часть данных просто куда-то теряется. Я сначала полагал, что проблема в куске:

```
    data = np.zeros(shape=((chunkSize,) + dataShape[1:]), dtype=f[data_path].dtype)

    imageNumber_variable = 0
    for imageNumber_file in range(start, end):
        data[imageNumber_variable,] += f[data_path][imageNumber_file,]
        imageNumber_variable += 1
```

который нужен, чтобы ускорить выгрузку данных из файла (если делать это напрямую - `f[data_path][start : start + chunk_size]`, то занимает в 100 раз больше времени, чем заполнение numpy.array). Поэтому я предполагаю, что проблема кроется в следующей части кода:

```
with ThreadFuture.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    tmp_return = executor.map(processing_chunk, func_arguments)

    for pixel_sum in tmp_return:
        intensity_total += pixel_sum
```

Привожу также полный скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf8

import h5py as h5
import numpy as np
import concurrent.futures as ThreadFuture
from itertools import product


chunk_size = 5000


def processing_chunk(file_info):
    filename = file_info[0] 
    data_path = file_info[1]
    chunk_start = file_info[2]

    
    with h5.File(filename, 'r') as f: 
        dataShape = f[data_path].shape
        imageCount= dataShape[0]
        
        start = chunk_start
        end = min(chunk_start + chunk_size, imageCount)
        chunkSize = end - start
        
        data = np.zeros(shape=((chunkSize,) + dataShape[1:]), dtype=f[data_path].dtype)

        imageNumber_variable = 0
        for imageNumber_file in range(start, end):
            data[imageNumber_variable,] += f[data_path][imageNumber_file,]
            imageNumber_variable += 1

    pixel_sum = np.sum(data, axis=0)

    return pixel_sum


def main(filename, data_path):
    
    global length
    global intensity_total

    chunk_starts = np.arange(0, length, chunk_size)
    
    func_arguments = product((filename,), (data_path,), chunk_starts)
    

    with ThreadFuture.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        tmp_return = executor.map(processing_chunk, func_arguments)

        for pixel_sum in tmp_return:
            intensity_total += pixel_sum


if __name__ == "__main__":



    filename = 'test.cxi'
    data_label = '/data/data'

    total_num_patterns = 0

    data_file_shape = (27270, 16, 512, 128)


    intensity_total = np.zeros(data_file_shape[1:])

    length = 27270
    
    total_num_patterns += length

    
    main(filename, data_label)


    f_name = 'parallel-av-num-patterns.h5'
    
    f = h5.File(f_name, 'w')
    f.create_dataset('/data/data', data=np.array([intensity_total / total_num_patterns]))
    f.close()
```

Буду благодарен за любые замечания/предложения.

Comment: `for pixel_sum in tmp_return:` можно заменить на  `intensity_total=sum(executor.map(..,`

Comment: imap вариант позволит поэкономить память и загрузить главный тред работой.

Comment: ThreadPoolExecutor не даст прироста производительности на математике